# Epiphany/Gnome Web applications not showing now it is a snap install in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap, webapps, epiphany

I have moved from 18.04 to 20.04 using a clean OS install and then re-installation of all used packages. One of the tricks I've used in the past is to create Web applications in Gnome Web (Epiphany) for frequently used sites. These would appear under 'Show Applications' and could be added to favourites in the dock and integrate with notifications etc.

This has stopped working in 20.04, I guess because the default Epiphany install is via Snap - the web 'applications' I re-created are now not shown at all under applications and can't be run in the same way. I can confirm that if I go to about:applications in Epiphany they are listed and are also in my profile under ~/snap/epiphany/current/.local/share/applications as .desktop files.

My installed versions
Ubuntu 20.01.1 LTS
Gnome 3.36.3
Epiphany 3.34.4-1-g606db9aec

A workaround to re-create the past functionality would be much appreciated.

Thanks
M

Comment: Are you sure it's a snap?  chromium was made a snap, and my own system has it installed as a *deb* package (which didn't install any snap).  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/epiphany-browser

Comment: Yes it is - definitely under ~/snap/epiphany and snap list yields epiphany           3.34.4-1-g606db9aec9  58    latest/stable    jbicha

Comment: Then why not remove your snap, and use the standard *deb* based one instead?  Refer prior comment (you installed the *snap*, either by command, or using a Ubuntu Software and not carefully selecting the non-snap'd version).  You'll also note the *deb* version is 3.36.3 in last comment  (this is what you've installed - https://snapcraft.io/epiphany)

Comment: Thanks for that - I just assumed that the snap install was the default and would work the same. You learn something new every day ;-D

Comment: Given that it's more likely you'll receive faster updates (and newer versions) of Epiphany when installed via snap, you should keep it and just symlink the desktop files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed the snap version (either by command, or using a Ubuntu Software and not carefully selecting the *non-snap'd* version)

**1. remove the *snap***

`snap remove epiphany`

this will remove

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   snap search epiphany
Name      Version               Publisher  Notes  Summary
epiphany  3.34.4-1-g606db9aec9  jbicha     -      Web browser for GNOME
```

or the version you mention - https://snapcraft.io/epiphany

**2. install the standard *deb* package**

`sudo apt install epiphany-browser`

this will install

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-cache search epiphany-browser
epiphany-browser - Intuitive GNOME web browser
epiphany-browser-data - Data files for the GNOME web browser
```

or https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/epiphany-browser

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the `snap` version, or just don't want to deal with uninstalling/reinstalling. I suggest you symlink the `.desktop` files from `~/snap/epiphany/current/.local/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`. To do so, on a terminal do:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
ln -s ~/snap/epiphany/current/.local/share/applications/* .
chmod +x epiphany-*.desktop
```

The last line is necessary to "trust" the desktop files, and show them as any other application. Without it, it won't work.

Comment: Nice - hadn't thought of that. I did the uninstall thing but might revert to this when I have a little more time.

Comment: Glad you like it, feel free to change your accepted answer if you want to 